.NET 8 Pagination <a>Page2...</a> hyperlinks not passing the viewmodels values to the controller
In .NET 8, I have a form with controls (dateFrom, dateTo these fields are passed in a viewmodel to controller). When "Search" button is clicked, the grid is populated with pagination.
After grid with pagination is loaded, my problem is in pagination. Issue is that when I click button 2 (ie <a>2</a>) on pagination, then in the controller the UsersViewModel that has DateTo and DateFrom values is null.
Please advice how to pass view model with DateTo and DateFrom values on the click of the page number 2, 3, 4, 5 etc.?
UsersViewModel:
public DateTime? FromDate { get; set; }
public DateTime? ToDate { get; set; }
 

UsersController:
public IActionResult UsersAction(UsersViewModel searchinput, int page = 0,int pageSize = 10)   //, int TotalPages = 0)
{
    // logic to return data
}

ViewPage.cshtml:
 @model UsersViewModel
 <form asp-controller="UsersController" asp-action="UsersAction" method="post">
     <input asp-for="FromDate" class="form-control" type="date" style="width:50%" />     
     <input asp-for="FromTo" class="form-control" type="date" style="width:50%"/>  
    
     <input type="submit" value="Search"  formaction="/UsersController/UsersAction" />
 </form>
    
 <form asp-controller="UsersController" asp-action="UsersAction" method="post"> 
     //Grid code  //my grid is getting populated
    
      @if (Model.Pagination.TotalPages > 0)
      {
          <ul class="pagination">
            @if (Model.Pagination.CurrentPage > 1)
            {
                <li class="page-item">
                    <a class="page-link" asp-controller="@Model.Pagination.Controller" asp-action="@Model.Pagination.Action" asp-route-page="1">First</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-link" asp-controller="@Model.Pagination.Controller" asp-action="@Model.Pagination.Action" asp-route-page="@(Model.Pagination.CurrentPage- 1)">
                        Previous
                    </a>
                </li>
            } 

            @for (var pageNo = Model.Pagination.StartPage; pageNo <= Model.Pagination.EndPage; pageNo++)
            {
                <li class="page-item @(pageNo == Model.Pagination.CurrentPage ? "active" : "")">
                    <a class="page-link" asp-controller="@Model.Pagination.Controller" asp-action="@Model.Pagination.Action" asp-route-page="@pageNo">
                    @pageNo
                    </a>
                </li>
            } 
          </ul>
 </form>

Please share your thoughts
